# Obtain the .bin file in android program

Tags: android, bin

I put the .bin file in assets of android. I want to read it. I use this root:

```
fis = new FileInputStream("x:" + File.separator + "work"+File.separator+"game1"+File.separator+"File"+File.separator+"game1"+File.separator+"assets"+File.separator+"01.bin");
```

but it is not right.  After run it shows can not find the file.  How to get this file?

Comment: You need to provide more information, but an Android app runs on Android which is Linux, and there definitely are no 'X:' drives. What do you mean by 'assets'? The `/assets` folder in your Eclipse project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with something like this :

```
AssetManager assetManager = getResources().getAssets();
InputStream inputStream = null;

    try {
        inputStream = assetManager.open("foo.txt");
            if ( inputStream != null)
                Log.d(TAG, "It worked!");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

For detailed example see this link.

[Android Read File From Assets](http://www.technotalkative.com/android-read-file-from-assets/)

Comment: FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(ImageUrl+".bin"); BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos); DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(bos);

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

```
AssetManager assetManager = getResources().getAssets();
InputStream input;
try
{
input = assetManager.open("01.bin");   
}
catch (IOException e)
{
e.printStackTrace();
}
```